# Systemverilog: assignment between unpacked arrays of different order (downto vs. upto)

Tags: arrays, system-verilog

Assuming two (edit: unpacked) arrays of int are defind with different index ordering (downto vs. upto) but the same size, like

```
int  a [10:1];
int  b [1:10];
```

would an assignment between these,

```
assign b = a;
```

1. be illegal, or
2. result in a "same index" assignment (b[1]=a[1] ... b[10]=a[10]), or
3. result in a "mirrored index" assignment (b[1]=a[10] ... b[10]=a[1])?

I have not been able to find information in the language reference manual, and two commercial tools are behaving differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is legal code and you are showing an *unpacked* array, not a *packed* array. However either way, the range goes from left to right. So your option 3 is the correct behavior. See section *6.22.2 Equivalent types* and *7.6 Array assignments* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)